# Generation of Random x-Bit string

Tags: r, random, bit

Is there an easy way to generate a random x-bit string, where x is the number of bits, in the R Programming Language?

Comment: Your question dont make sense. Do you mean x byte string? and even this depends on the encoding... maybe you can clarify your question if you give a bit-context..

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to generate a random string of `x` characters, then try this:

```
x <- 10 # some number of characters

paste(letters[ sample(1:26,size=x,replace=T) ] ,collapse='')
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `bit` package:

```
> as.bit(sample(2,x,replace=TRUE)==1)
bit length=50 occupying only 2 integers
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8          43    44    45    46 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    ..  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
   47    48    49    50 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The package prints them out as TRUE and FALSE, but you can probably make it do 0 and 1 if you want...

```
> x=50
> bits = as.bit(sample(2,x,replace=TRUE)==1)
> paste(as.integer(bits),collapse="")
[1] "11010000001100101001001101010001000101110001010010"
>
```